Why do the lancet drones for russia have x-wing?
I was looking at some videos of the war. The russian ZALA Lancet drones have an X wing configuration.
Why?
I looked up this book. It has a chapter on the X wings. Which says, that X wings can generate double the lift than single wing, but also upper wing barely generate any lift.
Is there any document explaining the wings and design decision of this drone?

Can you tell us in which chapter/article of the book you linked you have found that claim? The book is quite big.

@sophit
Page1176: The Aerodynamics and Hover Control for the [sic.] X-wing VTOL MAV

Having two wings staggered above one another is always disadvantageous from an aerodynamics point of view, as the two wings do not create twice the lift as an equivalent mono-wing (see biplanes). Additionally, having a second wind creates a second wing-tip vortice which increases drag.
However, the lancet drone is not a conventional aircraft but a loitering munition weapon, designed to be able to hit a ground target with high accuracy, which is why the designers opted for an X-wing design. The big advantage of this design, is that the lancet drone does not have to bank-to-turn, but can employ a skid-to-turn strategy (see also this book). This allows the lancet drone to adjust its movement direction faster than a conventional (mono-)plane. This means that during its final approach phase, the lancet drone can make course corrections not only by having to roll into the desired direction and then "pulling on the stick" but rather it can just "sideslip" - which decreases steering response time resulting in a more accurate guidance and therefore increases accuracy of the weapon.
To sum up, this design decision trades aerodynamic/power efficiency for accuracy.
So why is an X-wing type design well suited for this skid-to-turn strategy? Because with X-wings, you can generate lift not only in the vertical direction, but also laterally. More or less, X-wing designs are capable of changing flight directions regardless of their orientation, which enables them to fly up, down, left or right without having to roll in these directions first.
This strategy is also commonly applied by conventional missiles, for the same reasons. Additionally, it makes the GNC system simpler, as you simply deflect your fins into the direction you want to go!
Of course, I cannot produce a link or a document to proof this, as all of the design documents of this weapon are classified.

Hi @U_flow, thank you. But can you point me some work explaining X-wing skid to turn? Googling the term "Xwing slip to turn" is not returning anything but some movie CGI stuff.  Thank you.

@Sean I posted the wikipedia article explaining the Skid-to-Turn strategy in the answer (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skid-to-turn). Basically it just means that instead of first rolling to initiate a turn, you directly point your aircraft in the direction you want to go. Note that this is different from how a normal aircraft flies mostly. I tried to update my answer a following your comment above. However I am uncertain what you are confused about, therefore please ask and I will try to clarify my answer further.

For further explanaition please also see this book.

thank you. I just want to understand the concepts more deeply. my background is computational fluid dynamics. But I am interested in understanding the design choices behind these typeof things.

I'm sure you wanted to say "which decreases steering response time".

Yes, that is true. I will edit accordingly.

"Additionally, having a second wind creates a second wing-tip vortice which increases drag" having a second wing-tip vortex doesn't imply higher drag. Actually if the lift is shared among two wings like a biplane then the induced drag halves, at least theoretically.

@sophit to my understanding, the formation of a second wing tip vortice creates higher drag in comparison to a single one, as there is "overhead" included. But I leave the exact explanation to someone with more aerodynamic knowledge then me.

Simple mathematical explanation: induced drag is proportional to $C_l^2$. If you have two wings like in a biplane then each wing is generating half of the total lift and the relevant induced drag become $2 \times (\frac{C_l}{2})^2=\frac{C_l^2}{2}$ i.e. half of before

@PeterKämpf can you share your insights on this topic?

@PeterKämpf: please charge for your service

@U_flow At high speeds I do not pay much attention to induced drag, because friction is dominant. Having two pairs of wings where one would suffice will increase drag. Induced drag is important in the loitering phase, and here I expect not much difference to a single wing layout - if you look at the mass of air which is used for lift creation, it always is a circle with the wingspan as its diameter.


Why do the lancet drones for russia have x-wing?

They not only have x-wings but a canard configuration and a pusher-propeller as well. And everything points to some very good aerodynamics choices. Anyway wings and tails are not really arranged in a "X" rather in a configuration that I would call "double V" (or "><"): in fact if you rotate the aircraft 45° you won't get a perfect cross + since the angle between the two wings is not perpendicular.
The concept of using two wings one (more or less) on top of the other and the concept of the canard configuration both are aimed at reducing induced drag. Since the Lancet is flying at a relatively low speed, induced drag is going to be the highest source of drag during flight and it makes sense to reduce it as much as possible to extend its range and speed.
Theoretically, induced drag is proportional to the square of the lift $C_{d_i} \propto C_l^2$. Now, if you split the total lift among two wings, each carrying half of the total lift, then the relevant induced drag becomes:
$C_{d_i} \propto 2 \times  (C_l/2)^2 =\frac{C_l^2}{2}$
i.e half of before! And since the lancet actually has four lifting surfaces, the reduction in the induced drag is going to be of a factor $\frac{1}{4}$.
This result is obviously only theoretical: aerodynamic interference among the four lifting surfaces and the need for longitudinal stability will increase parasite drag and will prevent the perfectly equal sharing of lift among the four surfaces; anyway there should be a net gain in induced drag compared to a conventional configuration.
The pusher-propeller located on the tail is also helping in stabilising the aircraft longitudinally, further downloading the canard.
The fact that all four surfaces are (or seem to be) movable will also give an extremely manoeuvrable aircraft.
